# DataGridView does not update after submitting changes c# linq

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, linq-to-sql

I have a simple client registration form. I placed some textboxes next to a data grid view, so that I could add and update users. That was working fine and still does.

[image]

Recently, I have added a new windows form for client definition, so that when double-clicking a row a form with required field comes up that shows clients information and lets you change them. Clicking the "OK" button will save changes to the SQL database.

With the field beside the grid view, when I update a user info the grid view immediately gets updated and shows data, but when updating data with the new form, updates do not show in the grid view even if I double-click the row again. When I close the app and run it again I will see the updated data.

I have added an activation event for the main form to update the grid view with selecting data again from the database, but no success. This is the code that i am using for the update from side panel:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btnUpdate.Text == "Update")
    {
        txtUsername.Text = ClientsGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["Username"].Value.ToString();
        txtPassword.Text = ClientsGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["Password"].Value.ToString();
        txtUID.Text = ClientsGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["UID"].Value.ToString();
        txtName.Text = ClientsGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
        chkIsActive.Checked = (bool)ClientsGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["IsActive"].Value;
        chkItemListAccess.Checked = (bool)ClientsGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["ItemListAccess"].Value;
        chkMaterialSumAccess.Checked = (bool)ClientsGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["MaterialSumAccess"].Value;
        chkPartListAccess.Checked = (bool)ClientsGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["PartListAccess"].Value;
        chkPriceListAccess.Checked = (bool)ClientsGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["PriceListAccess"].Value;

        btnUpdate.Text = "Apply Update";
        btnSubmit.Enabled = false;
        txtUsername.ReadOnly = true;
    }
    else if (btnUpdate.Text == "Apply Update")
    {
        if (ClientFormValidation())
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(ClientsGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString());
            var SelectedUser = from Client in ClientsContext.Clients
                               where Client.ID == id
                               select Client;
            if (SelectedUser.Count() == 1)
            {
                Client UpdatingClient = SelectedUser.Single();
                UpdatingClient.Password = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
                UpdatingClient.UID = txtUID.Text.Trim();
                UpdatingClient.Name = txtName.Text.Trim();
                UpdatingClient.IsActive = chkIsActive.Checked;
                UpdatingClient.ItemListAccess = chkItemListAccess.Checked;
                UpdatingClient.MaterialSumAccess = chkMaterialSumAccess.Checked;
                UpdatingClient.PartListAccess = chkPartListAccess.Checked;
                UpdatingClient.PriceListAccess = chkPriceListAccess.Checked;

                ClientsContext.SubmitChanges();

            }
            ShowAll();
            ClearClientForm();
            btnUpdate.Text = "Update";
            btnSubmit.Enabled = true;
            txtUsername.ReadOnly = false;
        }


    }
}
```

and this is for Client definition form:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ISnewUser)
    {
        InsertNewClient();
    }
    else if(!ISnewUser)
    {
        UpdateClient();
    }
    this.Close();
}

private void UpdateClient()
{
    if (ClientFormValidation())
    {

        var SelectedUser = from Client in ClientsContext.Clients
                           where Client.ID == id
                           select Client;
        if (SelectedUser.Count() == 1)
        {
            Client UpdatingClient = SelectedUser.Single();
            UpdatingClient.Password = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
            UpdatingClient.UID = txtUID.Text.Trim();
            UpdatingClient.Name = txtName.Text.Trim();
            UpdatingClient.IsActive = chkUserActiveSatus.Checked;
            UpdatingClient.ItemListAccess = chkItemListAccess.Checked;
            UpdatingClient.MaterialSumAccess = chkMaterialSummeryAccess.Checked;
            UpdatingClient.PartListAccess = chkPartListAccess.Checked;
            UpdatingClient.PriceListAccess = chkPriceListAcess.Checked;
            ClientsContext.SubmitChanges();


        }

    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it myself,
i passed a Client object while initializing the client definition form.
so for updating i used exactly the same object not getting its parapeter and selecting it again from data base:

```
public frmClientDefinition(Client thisClient=null)
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            if (thisClient!=null)
            {
                User = thisClient;
                id = thisClient.ID;
                ISnewUser = false;
                txtName.Text = thisClient.Name;
                txtUsername.Text = thisClient.Username;
                txtPassword.Text = thisClient.Password;
                txtDate.Text = thisClient.Date.ToString();
                txtUID.Text = thisClient.UID;
                chkUserActiveSatus.Checked = thisClient.IsActive;
                chkItemListAccess.Checked = thisClient.ItemListAccess;
                chkPartListAccess.Checked = thisClient.PartListAccess;
                chkMaterialSummeryAccess.Checked = thisClient.MaterialSumAccess;
                chkPriceListAcess.Checked = thisClient.PriceListAccess;
                chkFullPriceListAccess.Checked = false;
                chkOfficialRecieptAccess.Checked = false;
                chkNonOfficialRecieptAccess.Checked = false;
                chkAdvancedPriceControlsAccess.Checked = false;
                chkFullPriceListSaveAccess.Checked = false;
                chkOfficialRecieptSaveAccess.Checked = false;
                chkNonOfficialRecieptSaveAccess.Checked = false;
                txtUsername.ReadOnly = true;
            }
            txtDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
```

and for updating this snippet:

```
private void UpdateClient()
        {
            if (ClientFormValidation())
            {
                    User.Password = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
                    User.UID = txtUID.Text.Trim();
                    User.Name = txtName.Text.Trim();
                    User.IsActive = chkUserActiveSatus.Checked;
                    User.ItemListAccess = chkItemListAccess.Checked;
                    User.MaterialSumAccess = chkMaterialSummeryAccess.Checked;
                    User.PartListAccess = chkPartListAccess.Checked;
                    User.PriceListAccess = chkPriceListAcess.Checked;
                    ClientsContext.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  *var SelectedUser = from Client in ClientsContext.Clients
                                           where Client.ID == id
                                           select Client;
```

It is Iqueryable, apply .ToList() to fetch into memory and then patch the change.

Instead i suggest , use this,

```
var SelectedUser = (from Client in ClientsContext.Clients
                                           where Client.ID == id
                                           select Client).FirstOrDefault();
if(SelectedUser!=null){
                    SelectedUser.Password = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
                    SelectedUser.UID = txtUID.Text.Trim();
                    SelectedUser.Name = txtName.Text.Trim();
                    SelectedUser.IsActive = chkUserActiveSatus.Checked;
                    SelectedUser.ItemListAccess = chkItemListAccess.Checked;
                    SelectedUser.MaterialSumAccess = chkMaterialSummeryAccess.Checked;
                    SelectedUser.PartListAccess = chkPartListAccess.Checked;
                    SelectedUser.PriceListAccess = chkPriceListAcess.Checked;
                    ClientsContext.SubmitChanges();
}
else{
//write your logic
}*
```

I am leaving exception handling to you only.

Comment: thank you, Sumit, but it did not help. GridView still shows old data, unless i close the app and re-open it again.